# Crop package for books, with content aligned to inner margin

Tags: geometry, crop

I am trying to use the crop package on a book document, but I would like to have a bleed area and crop marks only for the top, bottom, and outer part, not the inner one.

```latex
\documentclass{book}%
\geometry{%
    inner=17mm,%
    outer=15mm,%
    top=21.343mm,%
    bottom=21.343mm,%
    paperheight=8in,%
    paperwidth=5.25in,%
}%
\usepackage[width={10.5in},height={16in},lualatex,cam,axes]{crop}
```

With this (the size for the crop is exaggerated for testing), all pages are aligned to the top left corner, both for even and odd pages. If I add `center` to `crop`, it's all aligned to the center.

I have tried to look at the crop documentation, but could not find/understand much.

I am using lualatex, if that is relevant.

Edit:

Here is a full example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    inner=17mm,%
    outer=15mm,%
    top=21.343mm,%
    bottom=21.343mm,%
    paperheight=8in,%
    paperwidth=5.25in,%
}%
\usepackage[width={10.5in},height={16in},lualatex,cam,axes]{crop}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: do not show only snippets. It is much easier to test your issue if you provide a small but complete document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand the question, but you can define your own marks with the `\cropdef` command (see the doc of the `crop` package, section 2.7 "Defining your own marks").  It takes 5 mandatory arguments, the first four are macros assigned receptively to the upper left, the upper right, the lower left, and the lower right corner, the last is the name of the crop mode.

As example, the `cam` mode is defined (line 310) by:

```tex
\cropdef\CROP@@ulc\CROP@@urc\CROP@@llc\CROP@@lrc{cam}
```

To keep only the lower right corner, replace the other macros with `\relax`

```tex
\makeatletter
\cropdef\relax\relax\relax\CROP@@lrc{pinani}
\makeatother
```

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed to use macro names with `@` (see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/316068)).
Then activate this new mode with

```tex
\crop[pirani]
```

Full code

```tex
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    inner=17mm,%
    outer=15mm,%
    top=21.343mm,%
    bottom=21.343mm,%
    paperheight=8in,%
    paperwidth=5.25in,%
}%
\usepackage[width={10.5in},height={16in},lualatex,cam,axes]{crop}

\makeatletter
\cropdef\relax\relax\relax\CROP@@lrc{pirani}
\makeatother
\crop[pirani]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]